# I encrypted my phone (samsung S4) of which i dont remember the password. Need help to unlock it and save the data

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, encryption

I am using Samsung S4. I can't remember the password i setup while encrypting it. Is there a way to unlock the device ?

If it cant be unlocked how do i factory reset the device or i'll have to go to samsung service  center for that too.

Comment: If there were a way to get to the data without the encryption password, there wouldn't be much point, would there?

Comment: LOL...if there were a way for *you* to access your data without the encryption password, then other people would be able to do it too, no? ***Always*** choose encryption passwords for which you have a reliable mnemonic, so that if you forget exactly what it was you'll be able to figure it out. Unfortunately, if you can't guess the password, a data wipe/factory reset is your only option. No point going to a service center, because they can't decrypt your data, and you don't need their help in order to wipe it.

Comment: I have heard of people flashing the device with custom ROM's to bypass the lock screen and access your data. Not sure if it applies to your situation.

Answer (score 7):

**Master reset with hardware keys**

1. Turn Off the Device
2. Press and Hold the Volume Up, Home, and Power Button
3. When the phone vibrates release the Power Button, but continue to hold the other two
4. When you see the system recovery screen release the other two buttons
5. Using the Volume down, select "Wipe data / Factory reset"
6. Press Power Button to select it
7. When the reset is complete, choose Reboot system now and press power button to reboot the phone.

Disclaimer: THIS WILL ERASE EVERYTHING ON YOUR PHONE.  This does not solve the question about how to recover data that is encrypted.  It only answers the question about factory resetting the phone.